# Fichero se abre en local pero no en el servidor

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Quiero subir un archivo txt que ya está delimitado por comas y, cuando hago las pruebas locales con el siguiente código, me funciona como esperaba

```
$databasetable = temp; 
$fieldseparator = ","; 
$lineseparator = "\n";
$csvfile='c:/archivos/factura.txt';
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=agesacr_contabilidad;charset=UTF8',$usuario,$pass,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
$affectedRows = $pdo->exec("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($csvfile)." INTO TABLE `$databasetable`");
```

El código, en pruebas locales bajo Windows, funciona muy bien. Pero cuando lo coloco en el servidor web no funciona.

Para hacer que funcione tengo que indicarle como host el servidor.

Me gustaría saber cómo hacer para que ese código funcione en local y en el servidor. O poder subir el archivo al servidor (sin botton type file) y luego me haga el load data.

Comment: Puede que no tengas suficientes permisos, ya sea para ejecutar una sentencia load o para leer el directorio

Comment: no porque cuando hago un echo a la variable $csvfile me sale que esta vacía, es decir no me agarra la dirección o ruta del archivo

Comment: Lo que comentas es bastante normal. `c:\archivos\factura.txt` va a funcionar bien en local, pero seguramente en el servidor no porque esa dirección no exista. Y lo mismo con la conexión PDO, en local es normal tener la base de datos en localhost, pero por lo general en el servidor la base de datos suele estar en otra máquina, por lo que localhost no funcionará. ¿Te has planteado usar variables de sesión o archivos de configuración para esto? ¿Cómo haces los _deployments_ en el servidor?

Comment: si lógicamente lo saca por deducción que podía ser por eso porque busca los datos localmente donde esta el servidor ahora bien como sería las variables de session para subir archivos????